# How to run postgres in docker as non-root user?

Tags: postgresql, docker

I know that running docker containers as root is not secure, so I would like to change they way I run them. I have a container running postgres, which up till now was run as root (default). However, when I add this line to my `docker-compose` file:

```
user: ${CURRENT_UID}
```

Where `CURRENT_UID` is:

```
export CURRENT_UID=$(id -u):$(id -g)
```

I get the following error in the container logs:

```
initdb: error: could not change permissions of directory "/var/lib/postgresql/data": Operation not permitted

fixing permissions on existing directory /var/lib/postgresql/data ... chmod: changing permissions of '/var/lib/postgresql/data': Operation not permitted

chmod: changing permissions of '/var/run/postgresql': Operation not permitted
```

The situation is the same when running the `pg-admin` container, with the error message:

```
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/log/pgadmin'
```

The errors make sense of course, I am non root, yet postgres requires root access.

Does it mean it is impossible to run as non root?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Does it mean it is impossible to run as non root?

In fact, the postgres service *already* runs as a non-root user. The startup process for the `postgres` container is effectively:

1. Create necessary directories and set appropriate ownership
2. Switch to the `postgres` user
3. Start postgres

So if you start up the `postgres` image, even without specifying a user:

```
docker run -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=secret postgres:14
```

You will find that it's running as the `postgres` user:

```
# ps -fe
UID          PID    PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
postgres       1       0  0 16:11 ?        00:00:00 postgres
postgres      56       1  0 16:11 ?        00:00:00 postgres: checkpointer
postgres      57       1  0 16:11 ?        00:00:00 postgres: background writer
postgres      58       1  0 16:11 ?        00:00:00 postgres: walwriter
postgres      59       1  0 16:11 ?        00:00:00 postgres: autovacuum launcher
postgres      60       1  0 16:11 ?        00:00:00 postgres: stats collector
postgres      61       1  0 16:11 ?        00:00:00 postgres: logical replication launcher
```

It is entirely possible to *start* the image as a non-root user as well, but in this case you have to ensure that the necessary directories exist *and* have appropriate ownership. In an environment like Kubernetes/OpenShift the container orchestration system will take care of this for you when mounting a volume, but when using plain Docker (or docker-compose) you have to take care of it yourself.

Here's one way of doing it:

- Have an "initialization container" take care of setting volume permissions
- Start postgres only after the initialization container has finished

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  postgres-init:
    image: postgres:14
    volumes:
      - "postgres_data:/data"
    entrypoint:
      - sh
      - -c
      - |
        chown -R 2000:2000 /data

  postgres:
    depends_on:
      postgres-init:
        condition: service_completed_successfully

    image: postgres:14
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: "secret"
      PGDATA: /pgdata
    volumes:
      - "postgres_data:/pgdata"
    user: "2000"

volumes:
  postgres_data:
```

Comment: Thanks @larsks ! From the cybersecurity perspective, is it necessary to add this extra boilerplate to run the image as non-root, or it's fine to leave it as root, since as you demonstrated, the postresql process is run by user `postgres` inside of the container? What's the common sense approach?

Comment: I think the benefit here is minimal, since postgres itself is only ever running as the `postgres` user. You're never exposing a network service while the containerized process has `root` privileges.

Answer (score 2):

How I do this in Kubernetes:

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: db

spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: db

  serviceName: "db"
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: db
    spec:

      initContainers:
        - name: db-init    # using root, change permissions to not use root in main container
          image: postgres
          command: 
            - 'sh'
            - '-c'
            - |
              chown -R 999:999 /var/lib/postgresql/data
              
          volumeMounts:
            - name:  db
              mountPath: /var/lib/postgresql/data


      containers:
      - name: db
        image: postgres
        securityContext:
          runAsUser: 999  # postgres user in container
          runAsGroup: 999

        envFrom:
          - secretRef:
             name: db-env

        ports:
        - containerPort: 5432
          name: db

        volumeMounts:
        - name: db
          mountPath: /var/lib/postgresql/data

        startupProbe:
          tcpSocket:
            port: db
          initialDelaySeconds: 5
          periodSeconds: 2
          failureThreshold: 15

        readinessProbe:
          exec:
            command:
              - bash 
              - '-c'
              - >
                psql -h localhost -U "${POSTGRES_USER}" -c 'select 1'

          initialDelaySeconds: 5
          periodSeconds: 5
          failureThreshold: 5

        livenessProbe:
          exec:
            command:
              - bash 
              - '-c'
              - >
                psql -h localhost -U "${POSTGRES_USER}" -c 'select 1'

          initialDelaySeconds: 5
          periodSeconds: 10

      volumes:
    
        - name: db
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: db
```